# File extension not being detected for file upload

Tags: asp.net

Ok I have the following extensions I am checking in my code.

```
FileAttachments.FileAttachmentTypes fileAttachmentType = FileAttachments.FileAttachmentTypes.None;
```

The strings below in the conts are helled in a constants file
public const string wordExtensions = "docx;docm;doc";
public const string imageExtensions = "gif;tiff;tif;png;eps;raw;bmp;jpeg;jpg";
public const string excelExtensions = "csv;xml;xls;xlsb;xlsm;xlsx";

Which is then parsed down here
I am getting my extension from the File Info class as such

```
foreach (var fileAttachments in FormFile) {
  if (fileAttachments.Length > 0) {
         
    string filePath = Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Uploads");
    var tennantId = GetCurrentTennantId().Result;
    var settings = _context.SystemSetup.FirstOrDefault().UploadFolderPath;
    string uniqueFilename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + fileAttachments.FileName;
    string savedFileName = Path.Combine(filePath, uniqueFilename);

    FileInfo infoFile = new FileInfo(savedFileName); 
    string extension = infoFile.Extension.Replace(".","");
```

Here I check the file extension Parameter above  in the semi colan separated strings

```
if (extension.Contains(Constants.imageExtensions)) {
    fileAttachmentType = FileAttachments.FileAttachmentTypes.Image;
} else if (extension.Contains("pdf")) {
    fileAttachmentType = FileAttachments.FileAttachmentTypes.PDF;
} else if (extension.Contains(Constants.videoFormats)) {
    fileAttachmentType = FileAttachments.FileAttachmentTypes.Video;
} else if (extension.Contains(Constants.excelExtensions)) {
    fileAttachmentType = FileAttachments.FileAttachmentTypes.Excel;
} else if (extension.Contains(Constants.wordExtensions)) {
    fileAttachmentType = FileAttachments.FileAttachmentTypes.Word;
} else if (extension.Contains(Constants.audioExtensions)) {
    fileAttachmentType = FileAttachments.FileAttachmentTypes.Voice;
 }

}
```

Types is just an area for categorizing them into tabs for front end display

```
public enum FileAttachmentTypes {

    [Display(Name = "Microsoft Word")]
    Word = 1,
    [Display(Name = "Microsoft Excel")]
    Excel = 2,
    [Display(Name = "Image")]
    Image = 3,
    [Display(Name = "Voice Recordings")]
    Voice = 4,
    [Display(Name = "PDF")]
    PDF = 5,
    [Display(Name = "Video")]
    Video = 6,
    [Display(Name = "Evidence")]
    Evidence = 7,
    [Display(Name = "None")]
    None = 8,
    [Display(Name = "Notes")]
    NOTES = 9,
    [Display(Name = "Shared Case")]
    SharedCase = 10,
    [Display(Name = "Created Case")]
    CreatedCase = 11
 }
```

My Question is why is it not finding it for a word document of extension docx when its clearly there

Comment: Your logic is backwards. Instead of `extension.Contains(Constants.imageExtensions)` try `Constants.imageExtensions.Contains(extension)`

Comment: Seems like you should be easily able to test this, the logic itself has nothing to do with uploading files. Write some unit tests and debug them. Off the cuff I'd wonder if you have a case or culture problem. Consider using the overload that accepts a StringComparison enum. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @JohnWu Is correct here. I'd still strongly recommend separating things out into discrete functions and writing unit tests. It would have caught something like that far quicker.